# Forwarding variables between functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a calculation in the following code:

```
def traffic_intensity(count):
"""Number of cars passing by"""
int(count)
if count < 5000:
    level = "Very Low"
elif 5000 <= count < 10000:
    level = "Low"
elif 10000 <= count < 18000:
    level = "Moderate"
elif count >= 18000:
    level = "High"
return level


def number_of_busy_days(counts):
    """Busy days based on traffic flow"""
    daily_counts = 0
    for count in counts:
        if traffic_intensity(level) == "Moderate" or "High":
            daily_counts = daily_counts + 1
    return daily_counts

counts = [18000, 10000, 500, 9999, 12000]
print(number_of_busy_days(counts))
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to use the traffic_intensity function to calculate the number of busy days - a busy day is defined as having more than the "Moderate" amount of traffic given in the traffic_intensity function. I've tried a lot of different ways but I'm running out of ideas at this point.

The problem I'm encountering is that it doesn't find the level variable form the first function. I get the following error:

```
    if traffic_intensity(level) == "Moderate" or "High":
    NameError: name 'level' is not defined
```

Is anyone able to help me? Thanks! ^_^

Comment: You didn't say what problem you're encountering. What question are you trying to ask us?

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Comment: Ignore the indentation in the first one, I have it correct in my IDE, but tab doesn't work in the code editor here..

Comment: the objective of a function is to encapsulate code that is repeated many times, another objective is to make it modular and for that the code of the function should only depend on the inputs, if you need external data then it is an indicative of a bad design, and that is what happens with your code.

Comment: An additional problem is `traffic_intensity(level) == "Moderate" or "High":`, which works like `(traffic_intensity(level) == "Moderate") or "High":` and will always be true since a non-empty string is considered true.

Comment: ...and `int(count)` on its own does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You were passing in a variable `level` that doesn't exist into the function traffic_intensity. I presume you meant to pass in the variable `count`.

Likewise, having `or "High"` as a condition will always result in true since non-empty strings are convertible true in python

```
def traffic_intensity(count):
    """Number of cars passing by"""
    int(count)
    if count < 5000:
        level = "Very Low"
    elif 5000 <= count < 10000:
        level = "Low"
    elif 10000 <= count < 18000:
        level = "Moderate"
    elif count >= 18000:
        level = "High"
    return level


def number_of_busy_days(counts):
    """Busy days based on traffic flow"""
    daily_counts = 0
    for count in counts:
        state = traffic_intensity(count)
        if state == "Moderate" or state == "High":
            daily_counts = daily_counts + 1
    return daily_counts

counts = [18000, 10000, 500, 9999, 12000]
print(number_of_busy_days(counts))
```